# Expressing a statement in first order logic

Tags: first-order-logic

I am currently confused, below I have a statement and my expression of that statement in first order logic.

Reference:

W(person, song)

R(person, song, album)

**Statement: Every song that Gershwin wrote has been recorded on some album.**

**Answer: ∀y W(G, y) ⇒ ∃a R(G, y, a)**

However, my textbook answer

**Answer: ∀y W(G, y) ⇒ ∃a,p R(p, y, a)**

Instead of using Gershwin in the argument of R, why did it instead say there exists a person p? Does it really make a difference or am I still unclear about how expressing statements in first order logic work?

Comment: Because $p$ is the person who recorded song $y$.  So, if $y$ stands for "It's Wonderful," $p$ could be Barbara Hendricks.

Comment: Indeed, after David pointed it out below I facepalmed myself.

Comment: Apparently in R(person, song, album) the variable "person" stands for the recording artist, not for the composer. The textbook answer comes down to: for every song $y$ , if it is composed by Gershwin, you can be certain that it is recorded on an album $a$ by an artist $p$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because there is no guarantee that *Gershwin* recorded the song.  Someone else might have.

Comment: Oh damn! You're right.

Comment: I was under the assumption that Gershwin recorded the song too, but clearly that's not the case after you pointed out the obvious. I should be more careful on my part after this.